# Why is a setter for public field private on certain devices?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a public field and I pass a reference to its setter to a method. Certain devices crash when accessing this setter.

**Minimal example**

```kotlin
var isDurationValid = false

fun onHoursSet(hours: Int) {
    evaluate(hours, ::isDurationValid.setter)
}

fun evaluate(hours: Int, setter: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    setter.invoke(hours > 0 && hours < 24)
}
```

I have the following exception report on crash analytics on certain devices:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java.lang.Class<kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$FieldSetter$BoundInstance> cannot access private field

Comment: The error message clearly says that the field is *not* public.

Comment: I know that, but the field is not private else the code would not even compile.

Comment: Kotlin’s access rules are not the JVM’s access rules. I don’t know Kotlin’s rules, but since the declaration and the access seem to be in the same compilation unit, I would not expect any issue with the access, even with the most restrictive access modifier offered by the language. But the problem isn’t the language’s access rules, but the fact that a class `kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$FieldSetter$BoundInstance` tries to do the access, which is an implementation detail of Kotlin.